# Check for potentially simple proof of Brouwer's FP Theorem

Tags: general-topology, functions, fixed-point-theorems

This is for the special case of functions from and into the unit square ($I^2$) and is not mine but a friend came up with it.

Considering the function $f(x,y)$ defined on the unit square, we define the function $g(x,y) = f(x,y)-(x,y)$. Now, if a point $P$ is on the line segment $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$ then the $x$-coordinate of $g(P)$ must be greater than or equal to $0$, since the $x$-coordinate of $f(P)$ must be greater than or equal to $0$.

Similarly, if a point $P$ on the line segment $(1,0)$ to $(1,1)$ then $g(P)$ must have an $x$-coordinate less than or equal to $0$.

If we colour all points $P$ in the unit square such that the $x$-coordinate of $g(P)$ is positive red, all those where it is negative blue, and those where it is $0$ green, then the unit square can be divided into regions.

The leftmost edge of the unit square is red and/or green, and the rightmost is blue and/or green. Extend the unit square on the left and colour that area red. Then the red region must have a boundary within the square, and as $(0,0),(0,1)$ are either directly on that boundary or included within the red region, this boundary goes from top to bottom of the square.

This boundary must be green, as $f$ is continuous. Therefore, there is a path going the top to the bottom of the unit square whose image in $g$ has only points with $x$-coordinate $0$.

Similarly, we have a path from the left and right sides of $I^2$ whose image in $g$ has points of $y$-coordinate $0$. Thus, there is a point of intersection between these paths and at this point $P$, $g(P) = (0,0) = f(x,y)-(x,y)$ which is a fixed-point.

"QED" (maybe?)

Is this proof correct? I am aware it needs the introduction of some more rigour and further, if it is wrong, can this be fixed?

EDIT: Added colouring argument.

Comment: Can you clarify your 4th paragraph? I don't follow your existence of a 'path' argument.

Comment: I don't think you know that these "paths" are actually connected.  As yo move across, how do you know you have continuity across paths?

Comment: For example, as a diving in point to continue to tinker, suppose instead of considering $[0,1]^2$, you consider $X = [0,1]^2 \setminus \{\bar{x} \}$ for some point $\bar{x}$.  Let $F: X \to X$ via $F(x) = \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}\bar{x}$.  This is fixed-point free on $X$ (I've constructed this by 'hiding' the unique fixed point of the contraction in the hole $\bar{x}$).  What breaks in your argument? Something has to.  In particular, as Randall suggested, I suspect this has to do with your 'paths.'

Comment: This strikes me as amazingly similar to those false proofs that claim the Borsuk-Ulam theorem follows by applying the ordinary IVT twice.

Comment: My friend added the colouring argument above - is that good @Randall?

Comment: @Randall: Also, could you send me a link to a false proof of the B-U Theorem, btw? It sounds interesting (and/or amusing).

Comment: I believe the coloring argument just restates what the original proof attempt said.  There is still no argument to get the path connectedness of the green region.  The level sets of a real-valued function need not be connected.

Comment: He says that surely as there is a negative area that goes continuously from the top to the bottom, surely it at some point must have a connected boundary?